# View overlay on android

Tags: android, react-native

I have problem with overlaying view. It's styling in react-native (v0.24) 
A picture says more: 
[image]

On ios all work good. Bud android is always broken. 
View arrow spills over the edge. It is well. But Android can not do it.
Do you know what is wrong?
Thanks for the reply

```
  resultPillWrapper: {
    paddingVertical: 7,
  },
  resultPillInner: {
    height: 35,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    borderRadius: 20,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  },
  result: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  pointsWrapper: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  pointsText: {
    fontFamily: styleConstants.fontFamilyRobotoBlack,
    color: styleConstants.colorWhite,
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  positionCircle: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    width: 44,
    height: 44,
    borderRadius: 22,
    borderColor: styleConstants.colorSoftAmber,
    borderWidth: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FEEDD7',
  },
```

....

```
      <View style={[styles.resultPillWrapper, this.props.style]}>
    <View style={[styles.resultPillInner, this._getClassificationStatusStyle(classification)]}>
      <View style={styles.result}>
        <RunPill
          runNumber={classification.run_opponent_1}
          isAdditional={classification.additional_run_opponent_1}
        />
        <View style={styles.pointsWrapper} >
          <Text style={styles.pointsText}>
            {toTwoDecimalPlaces(classification.points_opponent_1) || ''}
          </Text>
          <ResultTableIcon
            result={classification.result_opponent_1}
            iconStyle={RESUTL_TABLE_ICON_STYLE.lightGray}
            imageStyles={{ marginLeft: 5 }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
```

Comment: Show me your code.

Comment: in ```resultPillInner``` i can change height to same like circle but i lost efect overflow

Comment: react-native android does not support `overflow` unfortunately